# Annoying Horizontal SCrollbar - Firefox and iFrames

Tags: firefox, iframe

I find that there is an annoying horizontal scrollbar that appears only on firefox (not IE or Chrome) when I use IFrames and content that is too big to fit within the width of the iFrame.

I have tried:
1. overflow:hidden
2. scrolling:no

I have no control over the content of the iframe so,i cant do anything about the width of the content.

How can I get rid of the horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

There is a

```
<iframe scrolling="no" ... >
```

did you try your (1) and (2) both in CSS?

doc: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/iframe/scrolling